# Line break on some Qtip tooltips

Tags: jquery, css, qtip

On this page: http://antidote.treethink.com/projects/
Some of the tooltips have a line break on them (#2, #8, #9, #10) in Firefox only
I would like to get rid of the line break on these but can't figure out why those have it and others (that are even longer) don't.

This problem isn't there in Safari.
I am using Qtip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) and the code calling everything is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#post-11 a[title]').qtip({
      position: {
         corner: {
            target: 'topMiddle',
            tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
         }
      },
      style: {
         name: 'dark',
         padding: '7px 13px',
         width: {
            max: 4000,
            min: 0
         },
         tip: true
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Wade

Answer (score -1):

I tried it in Firefox but none of them had linebreaks.
If you're still having this problem you could add the css

```
#qtip-content{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry, It's a class. It has to be: .qtip-content...  of course